# Mostrar error de formato antes de realizar acción Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo el siguiente post en mi vista:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Metodo", "Controlador", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })) {
<div class="myTabs">
  <div style="float:left; margin:5px;">
    Formulario prueba
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="lparametrosBorder panel-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        Fecha de movimiento:
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePicker, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DatePicker)
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-xs" style="background-color:#3399FF;color:#FFFFFF" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

Como pueden ver utilizo lo siguiente para validar que mi input no venga vacio:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DatePicker, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DatePicker)
```

Y en el `ViewModel` utilizo el siguiente `DataAnnotation`

```
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}")]
        public DateTime? DatePicker { get; set; }
```

Sin embargo cuando realizo la acción de `Post`, no me lanza el error dentro de la vista(si le mando nulo), si no que el controlador truena directamente y obtengo un error de Aplicación, como puedo obtener lograr mostrar el error antes de que entre a la acción del controlador?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si a la propiedad DatePicker le estableces `?` esto significa que admite valores nulos  y es por eso que nunca muestra el mensaje

establece el atributo required sobre la propiedad

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo DatePicker es requerido")]
public DateTime? DatePicker { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

para que funcione la validacion por data anotations son necesario los scripts jquery, jquery validate y unobstrusive

Comment: No puedo establecerla debido a la arquitectura de la aplicación

Comment: bueno de igual manera entonces, usa el atributo required en tu propiedad. luego al llegar a tu controller decides si la usas o no.

Comment: Intenté estableciendo el atributo required pero aún así está entrando al controlador y manda error de la aplicación

Comment: estas usando algun plugin?

Comment: Si, bootstrap datetimepicker

Comment: verifica que cuando renderiza la vista (osea el html) se estan incluyendo los scripts de validacion. jquery validate, unobstrusive,y jquery

Comment: jquery validate y jquery si el unobstrusive no, de que es ese js?

Comment: es una extension que utiliza microsoft en mvc para dar soporte a las validaciones a traves de los atributos data-*  , agregalo y proba

Comment: Tenías toda la razón, la agregue y ya funciona. Muchísimas gracias